# Xcode Framework Target - Getting error "Could not build Objective-C module 'MyFramework'" - But it builds successfully

Tags: swift, xcode

I've added a new target of type "framework" (iOS) to my project and added two swift files with public classes in them.

Then, I included that framework target in my app target by adding it to the "Framework, Libraries and Embedded Content" section.

Inside my app target, Xcode doesn't auto-complete the name of that framework, so it doesn't know it exists. But when I manually type it in and use some of its classes, everything compiles without a problem, even though I get an error "Could not build Objective-C module 'MyFramework'". This is really strange and I don't know why this happens. I tried removing the framework target and re-adding it, but the problem persists.

Any ideas what I can try? I don't even know where to look. I have no idea what this error means. I also have other framework targets in my project and they work perfectly fine.

As suggested on some other pages, I tried deleting the DerivedData directory but that didn't change anything.

I'm using Xcode 13, maybe this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out how to fix it but I have no idea why it fixed this. In my framework I had a `struct` with the same name as the framework/target. This caused the problem, it seems. I renamed the framework and now it works perfectly. Very interesting!